# Matlab kml to open in google maps instead of google earth

Tags: matlab, kml

My matlab is generating a .kml file and it opens in google earth. Is there a way to change it to open in google maps instead.

And also to discount the first values which is an unknown number of 0,0

Thanks.

**code**

```
kmlwrite('routetraveled', B.data(1:elements,4), B.data(1:elements,5));
winopen('routetraveled.kml');
```

I use this to generate the .kml and open it.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://chronicle.com/blogs/profhacker/easily-open-a-kml-file-in-google-maps/34835 or similarly http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/235/display-a-local-file-in-google-maps

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Ya I seen that, but that requires copying and pasting the link. I'm generating the .kml file myself and opening it with matlab, I'll post the code. I want it to open the .kml file in google maps automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if Google Earth supports it, but many apps allow you specify a file to load when you open the program. Instead of `winopen`, you would just make a command line call. Something like this:

```
!Path/To/Google/Maps --open filename.kml
```

Comment: so I should for the !Path/To/Google/Maps use www.google.maps.com?

Comment: No, I meant the app on your computer. Did you want this to open in your browser?

Comment: Well google maps is web based, well at least I don't have a app downloaded for it. So I'd like it to open in my browser.

Comment: There used to be (and maybe still is) a downloadable app. That's what I was thinking about. I don't how to do it with a browser.